# Find blocks with the same format with the find and replace function in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office

I am writing a glossary with MS Word and in the text I have interspersed blocks with different formatting. It is something like this (a bit more convoluted in fact):

> **term** /pronunciation/ ***word type*** first definition *example 1* second definition *example 2* ...

Is there any way, using wildcard characters in MS Word's find and replace menu, to select those individual blocks of the same format?

Note: I don't mean finding all characters with a specified format at the same time, but identifying each time a single block of common formatting (enclosed between blocks of another formatting). For instance, if I wanted to find blocks with normal text in the above example, the results should be each time "find next" is pressed:

> /pronunciation/

> first definition

> second definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use wildcards, in the search window, leave the "Find What" box blank and use the formatting of the text you wish to find.

[image]

Note that you can also use negative constraints for the formatting:

[image]

You can cycle through the options by using keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl-B for Bold, Ctrl-I for Italic, etc.)